# How to read files while preserving newline character

Tags: matlab

Is there a way to read a whole text file as string/character vector while preserving all newline characters?

I am using R2020b in Windows 10.

I tried `fscanf` with `rt` permission in `fopen` as well as `r` but the returned character vector removed all of the newline characters in the original file.

`readlines` would read a file into a string array of the lines. And by concatenating the resultant string array, the information in newline characters from the original file is preserved and useful for my purpose. However, I have efficiency concerns with this route. Similarly with looping with `fgetl`.

Is there a setting somewhere in `fscanf` or another function that can read a whole file as text while preserving the newline characters?

Comment: Did you try `fread`? It can read characters.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: As in searching for 10 in the result? And then whatever is in between, `char()` gets the per line text? I don't really know for sure what `fread` outputs.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: Actually `char(fread(fid))'` straight up works for my subsequent use. Now I wish I understand `fread` clearly.

Comment: `fread` just reads the data in the file. Use `char` or `char*1` as the format specifier.  Read the documentation to learn how to use the function. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html

Answer (score 0):

Using [readlines](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readlines.html), along with some string concatenation and the power of MATLAB's [implicit expansion](https://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/generate-code-with-implicit-expansion-enabled.html):

```
S = readlines('ex.txt');

out = S + '\n';
```